# How do I change the styling of a table using css?

Tags: css, reactjs

I am using the table class names in CSS to try and change the styling and it is not changing anything. I have just tried to change the background colour and border of the table to see if it working.

There are millions of other table stylings being used in my CSS file and they may be overriding things, some of which I have shown below, but I thought if I access the class names `.table`, `.slb-table` and `.table`, `.slb-tbody` then they should override these other styles. The `bg-color="red" className="text-white"` in the HTML table works.

The values in the arrays being mapped are not important. How do I style the component parts of the table in the CSS?

My React component:

```
tableData = () => {
  return this.props.sbranch.map((row, row_key) => {
    return (
      <tr class="slb-tr" key={`row-${row_key}`}>
        {this.tableHeader().map((value, key) => {
          if (value === 'invoice_val' || value === 'invoice_val_net' || value === 'profit_margin_val') {
            return (
              <td scope="col" className="align-middle" key={`data-${key}`}>{`£ ${row[value]}`}</td>
            )
          } else if (value === 'profit_margin_percent' || value === 'return_rate') {
            return (
              <td scope="col" className="align-middle" key={`data-${key}`}>{`${row[value]} %`}</td>
            )
          } else {
            return (
              <td scope="col" className="align-middle" key={`data-${key}`}>{row[value]}</td>
            )
          }
        })}
      </tr>
    )
  })
}

render() {
  return (
    <table className="slb-table">
      <thead class="slb-thead">
        <tr bgcolor="red" className="text-white" >
          {this.tableHeader().map((name, key) => (
            <th scope="col" className="align-middle"
              key={name}>{name}</th>
          ))}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody className="slb-tbody">
        {this.tableData()}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  )
}
```

My CSS:

```css
    .table .slb-table{
      background-color: #0004ff;
      border: black 10px;
    }

    .table .slb-table > .slb-tbody{
      background-color: #0004ff;
      border: black 10px;
    }

    .table {
      width: 100%;
      margin-bottom: 1rem;
      background-color: transparent; 
    }

    .table th,
    .table td {
      padding: 0.75rem;
      vertical-align: top;
      border-top: 1px solid #dee2e6; 
    }

    .table thead th {
      vertical-align: bottom;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #dee2e6; 
    }

    .table tbody + tbody {
      border-top: 2px solid #dee2e6; 
    }

    .table .table {
      background-color: #FFFFFF; 
    }
```

Comment: It is difficult to see exactly what is the problem here. Could you make codesendbox repo or something similar for us to be able to see the problem more clearly and help you

Comment: Have you tried using `!important`?

Comment: I couldn't do the sandbox and the !important did not work. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

you can change all with css

for exemple

```
table, thead, tfoot, tbody{display:block;}
tr {display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap;}
th , td{flex:1;}
```

Comment: can you show me what to type to just change the background colour in one component please? Then I might be able to work out myself how to change other things in other components.

Comment: as you asked your question it is very difficult to know exactly what you want, if you want to change a background-color : .yourClass{background-color:red !important;}

Comment: that does not work. whenever i do .table .slb-table {background-color: green} nothing happens. This happens whenever I try to change anything or access any table component. Or if I just do .slb-table{background-color: green} it does not work either. Adding the !important makes no difference too.

Comment: there is mayby a javascrip somewhere